# Custom label not displaying in custom cell. Storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I've looked through all the related questions and I still can't get this working.

I made a custom cell .xib (foodCell.xib) and set it's file owner to foodCell.h. I have also set the identifier to foodCell.

[image]

So far all I have in the custom cell is a custom label - `priceLabel` . The problem I'm having is I can't seem to set a value to the custom label or display it at runtime.

Here is my foodcell.h file:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface foodCell : PFTableViewCell


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSObject *foodCell;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *priceLabel;


@end
```

Here is where in my tableViewController file I configure the custom cell. All of the other label.text calls work fine, and the image displays.

My `NSLOG` call returns `null` .

Why can't I set or display this custom label?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"foodCell";

foodCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[foodCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

// Configure the cell
cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"foodName"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"foodDescription"];
cell.imageView.file = [object objectForKey:@"foodImage"];
NSString *myString = @"TEST";
cell.priceLabel.text = myString; //[object objectForKey:@"foodPrice"];
NSLog(cell.priceLabel.text);
cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines=0; // line wrap
cell.detailTextLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;


return cell;
```

}

Comment: if you log cell.priceLabel what do you get?

Comment: Did you registered your Nib with tableView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register you `Nib` with your `UITableView` in `viewDidLoad`

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"foodCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"foodCellIdentifier"];
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: create cell like below.

```
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"foodCell";
 foodCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: Is this what you need?

Comment: Thanks Bilal, this definitely has me close. Now that I changed my code to the register config you posted above, my initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle is no longer respected. My subtitle and image have gone away, and to see my customer priceLabel I have to click on the cell. What did I do?

Comment: @user3085646 You can set the Cell style to SubTitle style in XIB